# Error "Too many return arguments are specified. Specify only one."

Tags: matlab, simulink

I get this error "Too many return arguments are specified. Specify only one."

I understand what it means, but it does not make any sense. Since I have already two output blocks and scope in my simulink file.

[image]

What could be the reason for this error?

This my "error" code:

```
[tout,yout]=sim("TP_sub.slx")
```

Comment: Please don't just give a question the title "Matlab/Simulink" but choose a title of the question that is more or less a summary of your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your simulink model, the problem is how you call the `sim` function. If you look at the [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html), you see that `sim` only returns one output:

```
simOut = sim(modelname)
```

In earlier versions of Matlab, it was possible to add the state and output as additional output arguments, but currently you can only output a `simOut` object. 
This `simOut` object will contain some information, but by default it will not contain the simulation time and model outputs.

You can obtain this data by adding additional arguments to the `sim` call (complete list [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model-parameters.html)). For example, using the `'vdp'` model,

```
mdl = 'vdp';
load_system(mdl); 
simOut = sim(mdl,  'SaveOutput','on','OutputSaveName','yout', 'SaveTime', 'on')
```

you will obtain

```
simOut = 
  Simulink.SimulationOutput:

                   tout: [64x1 double] 
                   yout: [64x2 double] 

     SimulationMetadata: [1x1 Simulink.SimulationMetadata] 
           ErrorMessage: [0x0 char]
```

from which you can get the simulation time, output 1 and 2 by

```
t = simOut.tout;
y1 = simOut.yout(:,1);
y1 = simOut.yout(:,2);
```

Another option to get the data in your workspace is to add [To Workspace](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) blocks, like you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand what it means, but it does not make any sense.
>
> What could be the reason for this error?

Obviously you are not aware that `a` and `b` in the following example may be something **completely different**:

```
[x,y] = myFunction(someValue)
a = [x,y]

b = myFunction(someValue)
```

At least if the function `myFunction` is a "`mex` function" (and most Simulink-related functions are!), the function `myFunction` can be defined in a way that totally different values are returned depending on the number of return values given:

`[x,y]=myFunction(someValue)` may return two 10x20 matrices and `b=myFunction(someValue)` may return a single number (1x1 matrix).

You cannot just use `[x,y]=someFunction(someValue)` to "split" a single value returned by the function `someFunction` into two parts!

The `sim` function returns **one single** value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Comments . But actually it si possible to get multiple outputs from sim function . You just shoulld change" Model Confugiration Settings > Data Import/Export pane and UNCHECK Single simulation"